# Orbeon form submitting empty body

Tags: xml, power-automate, orbeon

I am trying to submit am Orbeon form to an endpoint (a power automate flow). However, all the endpoint is receiving are the headers.

We're using a hosted version of Orbeon forms so my access is limited to the UI. I've sent an identical XML from Postman to the automate flow and this does include a body.

Has anyone had any success submitting a form to an enpoint (Automate flow or otherwise), or does anyone have an idea of what's going wrong here?

Edit: Added screenshot of UI:
[image]

Comment: Hi Lars, how are you submitting the form data to your service? Are you using Form Builder, or is this something that has been setup for you by an admin (as you're saying that you don't have access to the configuration on the server)? Also feel free to include a screenshot of the UI you're using for this, as this might be more telling. -Alex

Comment: Yes I am indeed using the form builder. I've testet both through the configure endpoint menu options and by publishing and running the form. In both cases all I receive are headers. I'm suspecting that the package send off to my own endpoint is being packed or converted somehow (maybe as a bytestream?) but I really don't know and can't seem to find any documentation that would poiint me in the right direction - hence my post :)

Comment: Hi Lars, thank you for the screenshot and the additional details. What you have there is a customized version of Form Builder: that "Configure endpoint" dialog isn't part of the out-of-the-box Form Builder that ships with Orbeon Forms, so I am not sure what it is using under the hood. Do you have someone internally you can ask this question to? And just curious: you are saying that you are using a hosted version; may I ask if this is something your organization did, or a third party product? -Alex

Comment: HI Alex, thanks for your reply. Yes I work for a government agency and the Orbeon form is provided by a third-party provider. I'm afraid I'll have to engage the consultants then. I'll come back and update this question when I find a solution.

Comment: Hi Lars, yes, indeed, I think it is better to discuss this with the consultants that built this for your organization. And of course, they can chime in here if they have any comments. In the meantime, I'll just post an "answer" to the effect that this is a custom change done in-house. -Alex

Answer (score 1):

The issue is happening in code that was changed in-house relative to what ships with the "standard" Orbeon Forms. Thus OP will be need to ask the people who built this, as from the outside, we can't tell why the body of the request isn't being sent in this case.